# Execute Plugin Class from specific module in Magento2

Tags: magento2, plugin, after-plugin

I have created a custom reports using ui components.

For the export csv I have created a plugin class for this function.

**Vendor/Report1//etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Ui\Model\Export\MetadataProvider">
        <plugin name="custom_export1" type="Vendor\Report1\Plugin\ModifyExportPlugin" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
```

I have used the same plugin in another 4 modules.

**Vendor/Report2//etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Ui\Model\Export\MetadataProvider">
        <plugin name="custom_export2" type="Vendor\Report2\Plugin\ModifyExportPlugin" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
```

From the above code, if i export from any of the module, both the plugins are called, I need to avoid that,

When export is happened from Module Report1,the plugin from that module to be executed, if called from Report2, the plugin defined in that module need to call.

How this can be achieved? Can anyone help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what methods from the MetadataProvider class are you pluginizing? Or better yet, maybe you should also include the code of one of your plugins and explain what it does.

Comment: Check this post if it's helpful! https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256613/magento-2-plugin-to-run-only-when-function-is-called-from-specific-module

Comment: Are you create before, after or arround plugin?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, I used After Plugin

Comment: @BhaumikUpadhyay, the above solution is not clear.can you elaborate it please, how that can be used in my scenario

Comment: @Manjunath Sorry I misunderstood the requirement. In the shared link, the user wanted to run the plugin only if the method is called from a specific module.

Comment: @BhaumikUpadhyay, yes but i am not cleared how to use that solution

Comment: @Manjunath I have an open question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/318172/magento-2-di-xml-parameter-configuration-inheritance-explanation-with-example to understand the concept but still waiting for a better answer. The only reference I have is https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/256620/68003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem, but you may check the modulename of the request in your plugin methods and execute the code only if the request module name matches.

For example adding some code like this in your plugins may help you solving the problem (example for module Report1):

```
namespace Vendor\Report1\Plugin;
    
class ModifyExportPlugin
{
    protected $request;
    
    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
        
    ) {
       $this->request = $request;
    }
    
    //check the current request module name in your plugin functions
    if (request->getModuleName() == 'report1'){
        //place your plugin code here...
    }
}
```

In addition to have module specific controllers (for `gridToCsv` and `gridToXml`) you should create for each module a controller extending the original controller of the Ui module. Example for `GridToCsv` for module Report1 (place this content into `GridToCsv.php` in `Controller/Adminhtml/Export` directory):

```
namespace Vendor\Report1\Controller\Adminhtml\Export;

class GridToCsv extends \Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\GridToCsv
{   
        
}
```

Create a `routes.xml` file in `etc/adminthtml` of your module (if it not exists already). Example for module Report1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route frontName="report1" id="report1">
            <module name="Vendor_Report1" before="Magento_Backend" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

The definition of the ui component should be updated for each module like in this answer [How to override definition.xml file in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268277/how-to-override-definition-xml-file-in-magento-2)
Especially the `url`parameter should be like this according to the code above (Example for module Report1 and action gridToCsv):

`<item name="url" xsi:type="string">report1/export/gridToCsv</item>`

If you make these changes for all the affected modules, the approach should work.

Comment: hi @Helge, Yes I tried this, I am getting ModuleName as Mui, so this is not helpful.

Comment: OK, so your ui definition is not modified and all of your modules are using `mui/export/gridToCsv`or `mui/export/gridToXml`. One option could be to change the  controllers in the ui definition to have a specific controller for each module (e.g. `report1/export/gridToCsv`) and than you can use the suggested approach. The new controller do not need any logic just extend the original. See this answer how you can do that. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268277/how-to-override-definition-xml-file-in-magento-2

Comment: hi @Helge, so <item name="url" xsi:type="string">{your_frontname}/export/gridToCustomCsv</item> this line for creating custom controller, what code should i write in each of the controller, The answer is Incomplete there

Comment: can you please update here in your answer?

Comment: @Manjunath I have updated the answer, I hope that helps you to get the stuff running :-)

Comment: Thanks, No definition required in controller file? is that enough to go?

Comment: I guess that should work. You don't need other controller logic than the original only specific routes to identify your module